# How can I make equal padding in HTML dropdown options

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

so I am currently trying to make a dropdown with options that go
FullName | IDNumber

I was wondering if there is a way to add dynamic padding so that the "|" is lined up on every option.

[Dropdown Options Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgKVX.png)

Here is what I would want it to look like in a way.

[Dropdown Design Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtzmV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well if the names and IDs doesn't come with any interaction with DB try using extra space ( ) after the names.

Answer (score 0):

Display it in 1x2 box instead of 1x1.